# Finding out the values for which the function is not onto

Tags: linear-algebra

The question goes as follows.Let $$f(x)=\ln\ln\ln...\ln(x^2-\frac x2 +\frac{49}{16}+\cos4 \pi x)$$.Here $\ln$ occurs $n$ times.The question is to find out for what values of $n$ the function is not onto.

We see that $x^2-\frac x2+\frac{49}{x}$ has minimum value $3$ at $x=1/4$ and so also $\cos 4 \pi x$.which means that $f(x)\geq 2 \forall x$I am not able to continue from here.Any ideas?Thanks.

Comment: Just attempt to find the points of discontinuity. A hint: a point of discontinuity would arise if we come across a negative value's log, like $ln(ln(2))$.

Comment: If $f(x)$ is onto, then $\ln f(x)$ is onto as well. This means that you have to check wether $f_0(x)=x^2-x/2+49/16+ \cos 4 \pi x$ is surjective onto the positive real numbers. If it's not, try to see what happens to $f_1(x)= \ln f_0(x)$, and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call $f_0(x)= x^2- \frac{x}{2} + \frac{49}{16} + \cos 4 \pi x$. You have shown that the range of $f_0$ is $[2 , + \infty)$ (that's because $f_0$ is continuous and $\lim_{x \to + \infty} f_0(x)= + \infty$).

Now, for any function $f$, you have that $\ln f$ is onto if and only if the range of $f$ contains $(0, + \infty)$.

For all $n \ge 1$, call  $f_n(x)= \ln f_{n-1}(x)$.

The range of $f_1$ is $[\ln 2, + \infty)$.

The range of $f_2$ is $[\ln \ln 2, + \infty) \supset (0 , + \infty)$.

Hence, the range of $f_3$ will be $\Bbb{R} \supset (0 , + \infty)$, i.e. $f_3$ is onto. Inductively, you can conclude that $f_n$ is onto for all $n \ge 3$.